# How do I connect post types between them?

Tags: wordpress, tags, custom-post-type

I have pilots and airplanes (post types). I need to have:

**Pilot_1** has flown **airplane_1**, **airplane_5**
..
..

**Aiplane_4** has been in the hands of **pilot_2**, **pilot_7**, etc

How do I connect these post types so that on the post of pilot_1 I have links to **airplane_1** and **airplane_5**; and the same for airplane posts ?

One idea (the best I could came up with): create two more custom tags that represent the two post types and added them to the proper articles. For example

pilot_1 has the custom tags aiplane_1 and aiplane_5 with links to the pages of the airplane_1 and airplane_5 (www.website.com/airplane/airplane_1)

Is this a good thing (to me it looks a little bit hacky and this is why I have some doubts) or is there a better one?

Thanks,
Claudiu

Comment: use this plugin:- [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: I know how to do this (the practical is clear). The theory is a little sketchy. Should I be doing this (using extra custom tags for the post types), or is there another way ?

Comment: ACF can work fine. Normally, [Posts2Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) is the one most used by pros.